# C# white or black unwanted pixels appear in the image

Tags: c#, bitmap, picturebox, pixel

I am new to C#, I am using Visual Studo 2010, I have an image that needs to be displayed on a picturebox.
I tried many different methods. All the methods results in some unwanted pixels to appear along with image.
I have tried
picturebox.Image = Image.FromFile("bird.png");

result->
the image is displayed but with the stray white/black pixels at random places.

I also tried creating a bitmap of same size and drawing the image onto the bitmap and then assigning the bitmap to the picture box.Image. Still those unwanted pixels are visible.

I have tried clearing the picture box image (filling it with white or transparent) and then assigning the image, still same error occurs.

PS: this doesn't happen for all the images only certain images show this behaviour.

any help would be great

Code:

```
Image org = Bitmap.FromFile("bird.png"); 

Bitmap final = new Bitmap(org.Width,org.Height); 

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(final))
{
 g.DrawImage(org,0,0,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

}
picturebox.Image = final;
```

if i use final.save("picture.png"). The "picuture.png" does not have that wrong pixels, it happens only when i use picture box to display it.

Please find the images attached [defect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lqgW.png) [orginal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrGAk.jpg)

PS: its not because of different fileformat (orginal and defect)

Comment: Can you show (1) the original image (upload directly from the file that you're using in your C# program) and (2) a screenshot of the result (generated by the C# program). Don't forget to put the relevant code snippet here. There is not enough information yet to understand the problem. So a solution would be a roulette guess.

Comment: Never happened to me. So either you have a hardware / driver problem (then this is totally off here), or your input image has problems (which then is - guess what - totally off here with the question you asked). Load the image into some image manipulation program, zoom in and analyze.

Comment: Also always make sure to show only real code. `Image.FromFile("imagepath")` will surely not work at all..! Well, and accessing the image 3 times it not such a good idea either ;-)

Comment: Guys, anyone knows whats happening why is the image having white dots ? is it some rounding error ?

Answer (score 0):

It was an TransperancyKey issue resolved by setting it to Default.